# Analysis concerning derivatives

Tags: calculus

Can anybody help me with this analysis question?

> Suppose $\,f'(x) \ge M>0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. Show that there is an interval of length $1/4$ on which $\left\lvert\, f \right\rvert \ge M/4$.

I think you can use Mean value theorem for it. This is what I have so far:

On the interval $\,[x,\,x+1/4]\,$ using MVT 
$$\dfrac{f(x+1/4)-f(x)}{1/4}=f'(a) \ge M
\quad\implies\quad
f(x+1/4)-f(x) \ge M/4$$

Comment: Suppose the contrary and choose points $a\in [0,1/2]$ and $b\in [3/4,1]$.

Comment: im not sure what you mean could you elaborate or maybe write out the proof?

Comment: No. I want you to think. Suppose the contrary holds. Then...?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1]$.

If $f(1/2) > 0$, by your result, $f(3/4) -f(1/2) \geq M/4 \Rightarrow f(3/4) \geq M/4 + f(1/2) > M/4$. Then, since $f$ is strictly increasing $f(x) \geq f (3/4) > M/4$ on $[3/4,1]$.

If $f(1/2) \leq 0$, again by your result, $f(1/2) - f(1/4) \geq M/4 \Rightarrow f(1/4) \leq - M/4$ and then since $f$ is strictly increasing, $f(x) \leq f(1/4) \leq -M/4$ on $[0,1/4]$. That is in this case $|f(x)| \geq M/4$ on $[0,1/4]$.